# Assign Value to option in dropdownlist in mvc 4 razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dropdownlistfor

I'm quite new to MVC 4 so this might sound trivial.

Here is a piece of razor code:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ResidentTypes[i].LevelID, new SelectList(Model.LevelOfTraining, "Value", "Text", Model.ResidentTypes[i].LevelID), "--Select--", new { @style = "" })
```

It displays a drop down list with a few options and a **"--Select--"**.
But the select doesn't have a value assigned. Can any tell how to add value as 0 to the **"--Select--"** option??

Comment: This may help you http://forums.asp.net/t/1959753.aspx?Best+way+to+populate+drop+down+lists+MVC+4+razor+

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `LevelID` nullable - `int?`; I use extension method over the `SelectList` class.

```
public static class SelectListExtension {
  public static SelectList Prepend(this SelectList list, string text, string value, bool selected = false) {
    if (list == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    }

    return new SelectList(new SelectListItem[] { 
      new SelectListItem { 
        Selected = selected, 
        Text = text, 
        Value = value 
      }
    }.Union(list), "Value", "Text");
  }

  public static SelectList Default(this SelectList list, string text, string value = null) {
    if (list == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    }

    return list.Prepend(text, value, true);
  }

  public static SelectList Default(this SelectList list) {
    if (list == null) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    }
    // localization here
    string defaultMessage = "-- SELECT --";
    return list.Default(defaultMessage);
  }
}
```